# 3rd character index in a string

Tags: python, string, pandas, indexing

I have a String in python. From this string, I would like to write a function which returns the whole string until (without) the 3rd comma.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mystr = pd.Series(['culture clash, future, space war, space colony, society', 
'ocean, drug abuse, exotic island, east india, love, traitor])

def transform(s):
    index = 0
    count = 0
    while count < 3:
        index = s.str.find(',', index)        
        count = count+1
        index += 1
    return s.str[0:index-1]

out = transform(mystr)
out
```

This returns NaN. I would like:

- 'culture clash, future, space war'
- 'ocean, drug abuse, exotic island'

Could anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.split`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

mystr = pd.Series(['culture clash, future, space war, space colony, society', 'ocean, drug abuse, exotic island, east india, love, traitor'])
print(mystr.str.split(",").str[:3].apply(",".join))
```

**Output:**

```
0    culture clash, future, space war
1    ocean, drug abuse, exotic island
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
>>> mystr = pd.Series(['culture clash, future, space war, space colony, society','ocean, drug abuse, exotic island, east india, love, traitor'])
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> mystr.apply(lambda x : ",".join(x.split(',')[:3]))

0    culture clash, future, space war
1    ocean, drug abuse, exotic island
dtype: object
```

**Explanation:**

- Split by `,` and take the first three words by slicing like `[:3]` and join them again with `,`.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is to be taken to consideration, a list comprehension works faster since `str` methods are slow in pandas:

```
pd.Series([','.join(i.split(',')[:3]) for i in mystr])
#pd.Series(','.join(i.split(',')[:3]) for i in mystr)
```

---

```
0    culture clash, future, space war
1    ocean, drug abuse, exotic island
```

---

```
%%timeit
pd.Series(','.join(i.split(',')[:3]) for i in mystr)
#111 µs ± 3.58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%%timeit
mystr.apply(lambda x : ",".join(x.split(',')[:3]))
#180 µs ± 2.19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%%timeit
mystr.str.split(",").str[:3].apply(",".join)
#505 µs ± 5.54 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```